# Работа с объектами UI в другом классе Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу напрямую обращаться к элементам интерфейса, содержащихся в Ui MainWindow. Как это реализовать, не используя сигналы и слоты? Мне нужно передать ссылку на ui или вроде того.

Answer (score 5):

Просто сделайте метод для доступа к ui

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
public:  
    Ui::MainWindow *ui() const{
        return _ui;
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
};
```

Однако я бы все же посоветовал вам не обращаться к виджетам напрямую. Если вы решите изменить внешний вид `MainWindow` или отказаться от `_ui`, то вам придется вносить изменения во всей программе. Лучше будет сделать методы, которые будут манипулировать `_ui`. Примерно так:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
public:  
    void setAge(int age){
        _ui->ageInput->setValue(age);
    }
    int age() const{
        return _ui->ageInput->value();
    }
    void setName(const QString &name){
        _ui->nameInput->setText(name);
    }
    QString name() const{
        _ui->nameInput->text();
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
};
```